# Retrieve text in a column based on a substring in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, substring

suppose it finds some specific text like "sa" in A2,A4,A5,A6
i need to copy "sohail" in B2,B4,B5,B6 respectively, 
like this...

```
ImageName                   PhotographerName
pirf_20120523_sa0001.jpg    sohail
pirf_20120523_ml0001.jpg    manav
pirf_20120523_sa0001.jpg    sohail
pirf_20120523_sa0001.jpg    sohail
pirf_20120523_sa0001.jpg    sohail
pirf_20120529_sh0005.jpg    shirazi
pirf_20120523_ml0001.jpg    manav 
pirf_20120529_sh0005.jpg    shirazi
```

i tried to retrieve the addrres where it finds text...

```
Sub FindinTextInEachCell()

Dim rngX As Range


Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Find("sa", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Found at " & rngX.Address
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: See this link. `.Find` and `.FindNext` explained in detail. http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `Find` method properly, it'll only return the first `Range` it finds, you'll have to use `findnext()` method for subsequent ranges, but since subsequent ranges will duplicate, you'll have to compare it with the first address found.

```
Sub foo()
On Error Resume Next

Dim rng As Range
Dim prng As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
    Set rng = .Find("sa", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = rng.Address
        Do
            Set prng = rng
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = "Sohail"
            Set rng = .FindNext(After:=prng)
        Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Whoa! Why `On Error Resume Next`? :)

Comment: Agree with @SiddharthRout, `OERN` should be wrapped around the `Set rng = .Find` line and that's it, a global `OERN` should be avoided.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi, sorry for the late reply, actually I wasn't sure how to wrap it just aroung Set rng = .Find, therefore I did a global OERN :)